# Why google login redirect back to site with hashtag - can it be avoided

Tags: asp.net, oauth, google-plus, google-oauth, google-signin

I didn't succeeded to find any relevant answer to this so I must ask :)
I implemented google plus login to my site. With a few workarounds it work fine but...
When I am redirected back to my site from google I am returned to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/mysite/west/Default.aspx#state=/profile&access_token=ya29.qQDrtcVtgOEbS86Bg10puFG3dksJz74BlrEGulHldlJW2o5qQ6g7ilF17zQsm8iMLG0C82PQyp2Z-g&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

Because of this parameter here `#state=/profile&` I first have to read URL in javascript on load, 
remove this part to fix URL and then do this:

```
var url = "Default.aspx?" + queryString;
                window.location = url;
```

And then I can continue to read query string normally in code.
I don't like this because when I do this I make two postback on page and I want to avoid this if possible.
Is this redirect url must have this or this can be avoided? 
Redirect to google:

```
string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri="+this.Return_url+"&response_type=token&client_id=" + this.Client_ID;

        Response.Redirect(url);
```

When I get back to my site:

```
if (this.Request.QueryString["access_token"] != null)
            {
                String URI = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + Request.QueryString["access_token"].ToString();

                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(URI);
```

Comment: In your Google login configuration, what have you specified for your return URL?

Comment: Http:// localhost/mysite/west/Default.aspx

Comment: Are you using oAuth or oAuth2?

Comment: oauth2. I have updated my question with code samples. Can you please check it.

Comment: The first URL you have posted is the ID token. The ID token has to be validated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login
See step 3 onwards on how to do that.

Comment: You mean on access_token in url? In the last code in question I validate it. But to get it I have to fix url first as I can't get it because of hashtag in url. Or I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `response_type=token` to `response_type=code`. The callback URL will then have a `code` query parameter which is accessible server side instead of a fragment. You will then have to implement [step 4](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#exchangecode) to exchange the code for an access_token.